# rsync to remote server that doesn't have rsync installed

Tags: rsync

is it possible to rsync to the remote server that doesn't have rysnc installed?

I tried to rsync to our remote server that doesn't have rsync installed, all I received is this error:

```
bash: rsync: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(463) [receiver=2.6.8]
```

Answer (score 8):

You can copy the local `rsync` binary to the other server using `scp` and then use `rsync` with the `--rsync-path=PROGRAM` directive where PROGRAM is the path to the uploaded `rsync` binary.

For instance:

```
which rsync
/usr/bin/rsync
scp /usr/bin/rsync user@remote:~/rsync
rsync -a --rsync-path=~/rsync source dest
```

Comment: what will be the source and dest?

Comment: `source` will be the data to be copied, `dest` will be the location to put it to.